# how to overcome class loading issues in java when a class in JVM class path tries to access the class available in a web applications lib

Tags: java, jar, jvm, deserialization

I have a cache framework newly developed for one of our portal which will be used by many applications across portal. When the Heap size is exceeding certain limit we are persisting the cached entries to database.

Before persisting we are serializing the CachedObject and then storing into Database.

```
public class CachedObject implements Serializable{  
    private Object obj = null;      
    public CachedObject(){      
    }
    public CachedObject(Object obj) {       
        this.obj = obj;
}
}
```

Above is my CachedObject representation, obj is the actual object that is put into cache. Say obj is of type TestPojo.java and it resides in web-inf/lib of respective application.
This TestPojo.java is loaded by application class loader.

The newly developed cache framework jar (say cache.jar) resides in JVM classpath of IBM Websphere server and is loaded by ExtJarClassLoader.

I was able to serialize the cached object and save into database perfectly, but when I 
DE serialize the object saved in database I am getting ClassNotFoundException as the required TestPojo.java has no visibility at JVM Class path level(where cache.jar resides, here de serialization happens).

I knew that if I can move the cache.jar to application classloader level the issue will be resolved. But, I cannot do this because there are other jars with in the jvm class path that make use of this cache.jar.

Please suggest if there are alternate solutions to resolve this class loading issue.. by changing configurations at web sphere application server level or any other work around @ java code.

I have also tried different ways by changing the application’s class loading Delegation Mode to  parent_first, parent_last but I am getting the same de serialization issue.

Comment: IBM Websphere - there's your problem.  OSGi or Jigsaw would be the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Your caching framework should not use its own classloader for deserialization, but the application one. So for each application you need to keep track what classloader to use.

See also the API of the JSR107 caching standard, which needs to solve this problem also. A CacheManager can be retrieved with a specific class loader via the [CachingProvider](https://github.com/jsr107/jsr107spec/blob/master/src/main/java/javax/cache/spi/CachingProvider.java).